# Accessing ArrayList from JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist, jstl

I'm trying to code a simple support ticket system. I have the following code:

The Ticket class:

```
public class Ticket implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4585877638895523067L;

private int ticketID;
private int userID;
private String topic;
private String desc;
private String category;
private int state;
private String answer;

public Ticket(int ID, int userID, String topic, String desc, String category, int state, String answer){
    this.ticketID = ID;
    this.userID = userID;
    this.topic = topic;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.category = category;
    this.state = state;
    this.answer = answer;
}

public int getTicketid() {
    return ticketID;
}

public int getUserid() {
    return userID;
}

public String getTopic() {
    return topic;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public int getState() {
    return state;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}
```

}

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    session = request.getSession(true);
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
    if (session.getAttribute("isLoged") == null || session.getAttribute("isLoged").equals(false)) {
        dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Login");
    }else{
        du = new DAOUser();
        ticketlist = du.getTickets((Integer)session.getAttribute("userid"));
        session.setAttribute("tickets", ticketlist);
        dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/account.jsp");
        if(action!=null){

        }
    }
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);  
}
```

And finally the jsp file were I'm trying to display the data of the tickets.

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.tickets}" var="ticket">
    <tr>
        <td>${ticket.ticketID}</td>
        <td>${ticket.topic}</td>
        <td>${ticket.category}</td>
        <td>${ticket.status}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

The UserDAO class used in the Servlet provides an `ArrayList` formed by Ticket objects. With that code the table shows nothing inside... I have already tried different techniques for accesing and displaying the data but can't get it done.

Comment: Have you checked that ticketlist is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.tickets}" var="ticket">
```

try

```
 <c:forEach items="${tickets}" var="ticket">
```

Comment: I tried before... It was a mistake in the code I'm adding the list to the session.

Comment: Can you try to put some alert/sysout just to debug it and make sure that block is getting executed. You can also look for the java file created for this jsp under Tomcat -- work -- Catalina-- localhost-- projectname-- org-- apache-- jsp--Your.jsp and Your.java

Comment: I put an Alert in the foreach and is not being executed... But don't know why. When I enter to the tomcat to view its jsp is there with the forEach...

Comment: Can you provide JSP here.